# Unrecognized expression in php's $_POST

Tags: php

I have a piece of code like:

```
if ( (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] != 'check') || (isset($_POST['action'])) ) 
    $action = ((isset($_REQUEST['listing']) && $_REQUEST['listing'] != 'placements') ? $_REQUEST['action'] : $_POST['action']);
```

and when I compile it returns an "jquery-2.2.3.min.js?ver=2.2.3:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Notice: Undefined index: action in ..." and it looks weird because there's the previous if clause which should avoid that kind of error if it is not set... what I have missed?

Thanks! Cheers! Luigi

Comment: *"what I have missed?"* - the rest of your code related to those arrays and possibly more.

Comment: We need more code. Post the rest.

Comment: `? $_REQUEST['action'] : $_POST['action']);` => `? $_REQUEST['action'] : '');` try that. or post full code. I hate guessing. It makes me looks bad ;-)

Comment: 'action' is related to different situations like loading a grid or saving data in grid to db or deleting data...otherwise doing a check of data... and those are sent from ajax call...